# what does ゴゴゴ.. means?

Tags: words

This one often used with emojis/sticker while chatting online. Till now, I haven't seen it's use in spoken language. It seems to be slang. Is there any indirect meaning other than English equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

It's an onomatopoeiac phrase, that's meant to convey a menacing aura (like a thudding background noise).

It gained particular prominance in the manga "Jojo's Bizarre Adventure" where it was possibly the most common sound effect. Since then, it's become a meme to use the sound effect in a font similar to the one in Jojo's to make people appear more menacing.

(So yes, it is a Jojo reference.)